# Representation of the space of lattices in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, lattices

The space of 2D lattices in $\Bbb R^2$ can be represented with the two Eisenstein series $G_4$ and $G_6$. Each lattice uniquely maps to a point in $\Bbb C^2$ using these two invariants, and the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ map to the unit square and triangular lattices.

This representation requires us to treat $\Bbb R^2$ as being isomorphic to $\Bbb C$, so that we can evaluate, for some lattice $\Lambda(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ generated by $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$

$$
G_k(\Lambda) = \Bbb \sum_{0 \neq \omega \in \Lambda(\omega_1, \omega_2)} \frac{1}{\omega^k}
$$

where each element $\omega \in \Lambda$ is then treated as having the algebra structure from $\Bbb C$.

The above is often treated in the setting of modular forms, where it is assumed that everything is in $\Bbb C$ from the start, and that one of the lattice vectors is $1$. However, it is also given fairly often as an equivalent treatment in terms of real lattices.

So the basic question is, how do you develop a similar theory for $\Bbb R^n$? Is there a similar algebra structure one can place on $\Bbb R^n$ taking the place of $\Bbb C$?

Or, is there a simpler moduli space if we let there be different equivalent versions of the same lattice, e.g. "signed" lattices or something like that?

**My big-picture questions**:

1. What is a direct formula to represent the space of lattices in $\Bbb R^n$, so that every lattice corresponds to a unique point?
2. If the above is too complicated, is there an easier representation if we allow for things like "signed lattices," or allow different automorphisms of the same lattice to be represented with different elements of the same space, etc? (As an example, in $\Bbb R^2$, suppose we differentiated between two 90 degree rotations of the square lattice, or three 60 degree rotations of the triangular lattice, while equivocating between any 180 degree rotation of the same lattice.)

Assuming some generalization of the Eisenstein series is relevant, then the follow-up questions would be

3. How do you generalize the Eisenstein series to lattices in $\Bbb R^3$, or $\Bbb R^n$ in general?
4. Assuming you manage to do that, the space of lattices for $\Bbb R^n$ should have dimension $n^2$. Which Eisenstein invariants are needed to uniquely represent this space of lattices?
5. The Eisenstein/Weierstrass invariants can be viewed as coefficients from the Laurent expansion of the Weierstrass elliptic function. Is the above simplified from looking at the Laurent expansions of higher-dimensional elliptic functions?

I have been pointed in a few interesting directions - [Eisenstein Series on Real, Complex, and Quaternionic Half-Spaces](https://msp.org/pjm/1988/133-2/pjm-v133-n2-p08-s.pdf), [Eisenstein Series in Complexified Clifford Analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.493.9518&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [Generalization of Weierstrass Elliptic functions to $\Bbb R^n$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9506060.pdf), [On a New Type of Eisenstein Series in Clifford Analysis](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0232-2064&vol=20&iss=4&rank=12), [Clifford analysis with generalized elliptic and quasi elliptic functions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245495137_Clifford_Analysis_with_Generalized_Elliptic_and_Quasi_Elliptic_Functions). People have suggested the theory of automorphic forms and the Langlands' Eisenstein series.

However, I have somehow been unable to unpack all this to get a simple definition of the space of n-dimensional real lattices. I would assume that some generalized Eisenstein series would be necessary, but I don't know how to build them for arbitrary $\Bbb R^n$. Some of the suggestions for replacing $\Bbb C$ with an arbitrary Clifford algebra can sometimes equivocate between different lattices. For instance, even in the simplest case of $\Bbb R^4$, where we can treat the entire thing as the quaternion algebra, we tend to have that the lattices $\Lambda(1,2\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3)$ and $\Lambda(1,\mathbf e_1,2\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3)$ produce the same Eisenstein series, if we naively use the formula $\sum_{0 \neq \omega \in \Lambda} \frac{1}{\omega^k}$.

This was originally posted and bountied at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260577/using-eisenstein-series-to-represent-the-space-of-lattices-generalization-to

I am hoping for some basic explication of how to do this that doesn't require extremely deep knowledge of elliptic curve geometry and etc - I just want a basic representation for the space of $n$-d lattices.

**EDIT**: some have also mentioned the **Chabauty space** $\cal C(\Bbb R^n)$ of $\Bbb R^n$, which is the compactification of the space of lattices in that it is the space of all closed subgroups of $\Bbb R^n$. Elements in the Chabauty space are isomorphic to $\Bbb R^p \times \Bbb Z^q$, where $p+q \leq n$. For any closed subgroup, the tuple $(p,q)$ is the *type* of the subgroup, and the set of all such $\cal C^{(p,q)}(\Bbb R^n)$ form a **stratification** of $\cal C(\Bbb R^n)$ (note that the set of all $\cal C^{(p,0)}$ is the Grassmannian). As some have mentioned, if $n>2$, this is not a manifold, but it does seem to be a "pseudo-manifold" which is a union of manifolds that have been glued together, and the set $\cal C^{(p,q)}(\Bbb R^n)$ seems to be a manifold for any $p,q$, as shown in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.2111.pdf). Perhaps useful, although seems that it may be more general than necessary...

Comment: Not an answer, but seems relevant. If you compactify the space of lattice into the space of all closed subgroups, you get a space that is called the *Chabauty space* of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in which the space of lattice is a open dense subset. When $n=2$, by a Theorem by Hubbard and Pourezza this space is a $4$-sphere in which lattices form a somewhat complicated subspace (a suspension of a trefoil knot is involved). When $n>2$, this space is not a manifold anymore, and its topology is poorly understood. I thus guess that a simple representation into a simple space is a bit too much to expect.

Comment: In general it can always be described as $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$. It has a natural compactification, namely the space $\mathrm{Sub}(\mathbf{R}^n)$ of closed subgroups of $\mathbf{R}$ with the Chabauty topology. For $n=1$ the latter is a segment. For $n=2$, surprisingly this is homeomorphic to a 4-sphere (Hubbard-Pourezza 1979). For $n\ge 3$ it is easily seen not to be a manifold even with boundary; however for all $n$ it has a "Goresky-MacPherson stratification" (Kloeckner 2009) and in particular is locally contractible, also it is simply connected (Kloeckner).

Comment: Wow we posted almost the same comment in 15 seconds...

Comment: Thanks - so then I am wondering if one could, as an example, have a better-formed space of lattices if we let some nontrivial automorphisms denote "different" lattices? As an example, we could have "signed lattices", or let the four 90 degree rotations of the square lattice be "different" objects, etc.

Comment: BTW, this is a great read on Chabauty spaces in $\Bbb R^n$ - https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.2111.pdf

Comment: Every element in the Chabauty space is isomorphic to something of the form $\Bbb R^p \times \Bbb Z^q$, where the $(p,q)$ is the *signature* of the subgroup. The "stratification" of the space is into sets that all have the same signature, which they write as $\cal C^{(p,q)}$. It seems like each of these are manifolds, and the entire space is a "pseudomanifold" which is a gluing together of these sub-manifolds, with a few points being identified in such a way that it makes the entire thing only a pseudomanifold rather than a manifold.

Comment: If one wanted to classify "metric lattices" (in the sense of pairs $\Lambda$, metric $Q:\Lambda\times\Lambda\to \mathbb{R}$) shouldn't one consider $\mathrm{SO}_n\!\!\setminus\!\!\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$? Would this be interesting?

Comment: It would be, as I ultimately am looking to put the structure of a metric space on lattices, although how would you construct that?

Comment: It's obvious that $C^{(p,q)}$ is a manifold (as homogeneous space of a Lie group) and that the Chabauty space is union of these subsets. What's not obvious is that the "gluing" satisfies some reasonable properties (the notion of Goresky-MacPherson stratification, which implies locally contractible). It's not known, I think, whether it's triangulable.

Comment: Well, I would be happy to have a basic starting point even for just the individual $\cal C^{(p,q)}$, treated as individual manifolds without being glued together at all. I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Do we know what points are being identified in the gluing?